# Setting arguments in a kernel in OpenCL causes error

Tags: c, linux, parallel-processing, opencl, gpgpu

I am a beginner in OpenCL and thus writing a simple program to double the elements of an array.
The kernel code is:-

```
__kernel void dataParallel(__global int* A, __global int* B)
{
    int base = get_local_id(0);
    B[base]=A[base]+A[base];
}
```

The local_work_size=32 as I am squaring 32 elements.

In my program I have declared an integer array which holds the elements to be squared.

```
int *A;
A=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*64);
for (i=0; i < 32; i++) {            A[i] = i;   }
```

`platforms[i]` stores the platform id, `devices[j]` stores the corresponding device id. Their types:

```
cl_platform_id* platforms;
cl_device_id* devices;
```

Creating context

```
cl_context context=clCreateContext(NULL,1,&devices[j],NULL,NULL,NULL);
```

Next comes the command queue

```
cl_command_queue cmdqueue=cmdqueue=clCreateCommandQueue(context,devices[j],NULL,&err);
```

Next I created 2 memory buffers, one to hold the input data and the other to hold the result.

```
cl_mem  Abuffer,Bbuffer;
Abuffer=clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE ,32*sizeof(int),NULL,&err);
Bbuffer=clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE ,32*sizeof(int),NULL,&err);
```

Then I copied the data of array A to Abuffer

```
ret=clEnqueueWriteBuffer(cmdqueue, Abuffer, CL_TRUE, 0, 32*sizeof(int), A, 0, NULL, NULL);
printf("%d",ret);//output is 0 thus data written successfully into the buffer
```

The kernel code was then read into a character string `source_str` and the program was created.

```
kernelprgrm=clCreateProgramWithSource(context,1,(const char **)&source_str,(const size_t *)&source_size,&err);
    if(!err)
    {
        printf("\nKernel program created successfully\n");
    }//Outputs -Kernel program created successfully
```

I then built the program using:

```
ret=clBuildProgram(kernelprgrm,1,&devices[j],NULL,NULL,NULL);//returns CL_SUCCESS
```

Getting buildinfo next

```
ret=clGetProgramBuildInfo(kernelprgrm,devices[j], CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_STATUS ,0,NULL,&size);//Returns success
```

Creating kernel

```
kernel = clCreateKernel(kernelprgrm, "dataParallel", &ret);
    printf("\nReturn kernel program=%d",ret);
    if(!ret)
    {
        printf("\nProgram created successfully!\n");
    }
    //Outputs -Program created successfully!
```

Now comes the devil:-

```
ret=clSetKernelArg(kernel,0,sizeof(cl_mem),(void *) Abuffer);
printf("\nKernel argument 1 ret=%d",ret);

ret=clSetKernelArg(kernel,1,sizeof(cl_mem),(void *) Bbuffer);
printf("\nKernel argument 2 ret=%d",ret);
```

Both return **-38** meaning **`CL_INVALID_MEM_OBJECT`**.

**P.S.:As per the errors pointed out i.e. use &Abuffer instead of Abuffer in the argument and after making the necessary changes, both return 0**

```
size_t global_item_size = 32;
size_t local_item_size = 32;
```

Also `ret = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(cmdqueue, kernel, 1, NULL,&global_item_size, &local_item_size, 0, NULL, NULL);` returns **0**.

Trying to get the result

```
ret = clEnqueueReadBuffer(cmdqueue, Bbuffer, CL_TRUE, 0, 32*sizeof(int), B, 0, NULL, NULL);` 
printf("\nB:-\n");
for (t=0; t < 32; t++) {
            printf("%d\t ", B[t]);
                }
```

This returns buildstatus=0 with core getting dumped for my AMD GPU (running AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing platform) and NVIDIA GPU whereas it works **perfectly fine if the selected device is CPU using Intel(R) OpenCL platform**.

Also I tried getting the build log using:

```
cl_build_status *status=(cl_build_status *)malloc(sizeof(cl_build_status )*size);
clGetProgramBuildInfo(kernelprgrm,devices[j], CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_STATUS ,size,status,NULL);
printf("\nBuild status=%d\n",*status);
```

//Getting build info if not successful

```
clGetProgramBuildInfo(kernelprgrm,devices[i], CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG ,0,NULL,&size);
char *buildlog=(char*)malloc(size);
clGetProgramBuildInfo(kernelprgrm,devices[i], CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG ,size,buildlog,NULL);
printf("\n!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!Program ended!!!!!!!!!!!\n");
printf("\n\nBuildlog:   %s\n\n",buildlog);
```

But it returns `Buildlog:   Compilation started
Compilation done
Linking started
Linking done
Device build started
Device build done
Kernel <dataParallel> was successfully vectorized (4)
Done.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what the OpenCL 1.2 spec has to say about setting buffers as kernel arguments:

> If the argument is a memory object (buffer, image or image array), the arg_value entry will be a pointer to the appropriate buffer, image or image array object.

So, you need to pass a *pointer* to the `cl_mem` objects:

```
ret=clSetKernelArg(kernel,0,sizeof(cl_mem),(void *) &Abuffer);
```

Comment: It is working! 1 bug removed. But `ret = clEnqueueReadBuffer(cmdqueue, Bbuffer, CL_TRUE, 0, 32*sizeof(int), B, 0, NULL, NULL);` and then `for (t=0; t < 64; t++) {
    printf("%d\t ", B[t]);
     } ` results in garbage values.

Comment: Plus this code works on CPU(Intel platform) somehow when running it on AMD platform leads to segmentation fault! @jprice

Comment: Would need to see more more (e.g. kernel enqueues) to try and diagnose.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using clEnqueueTask? I think you should use clEnqueueNDRangeKernel if you have parallel work to do. Also, just set the global work size; pass NULL for the local work group size. 32x32 is larger than some devices can do.

Comment: Well, using local_id is also an error for that specific kernel. Queueing 2 work groups will lead to wrong results. And using only 1 work group is unefficient.

Comment: And in which case should I use `clEnqueueTask`

Comment: @DarkZeros is right, you should use globa_id(0). You should never use clEnqueueTask. It's not for data parallel work. It's equivalent to running a single work item, which is not efficient on a GPU capable of doing hundreds or thousands at once.